# Javascript - indexOf not work if identical elements are in the array at different position

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I'm using `indexOf()` to get the index of an element inside an array.

```js
    fs.readFile(filename, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, (error, data) => {
        if( error ) return new Error(error);
        let selectedWord;
        let charMap = [];
        let splittedWord;
        let output;

        const d = data.split('\n');
        for(let i = d.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
            const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            const tmp = d[i];
            d[i] = d[r];
            d[r] = tmp;
            selectedWord = d[r];
        }
    
        splittedWord = selectedWord.split('');
        splittedWord.forEach( (char, i) => {
            charMap.push(char);
        });
        //console.log(charMap);    

        console.log(`Selected word length is ${splittedWord.length}`);
        
        let dropped = 0;
        let mid = Math.floor(splittedWord.length / 2);
        console.log(`Removed letters: ${mid}`);
        for (let e = 0; e < splittedWord.length; e++) {
            // probability we should drop this one is
            // (desiredDropped - dropped) / (word.length - e)
            if( Math.random() < (mid - dropped) / (splittedWord.length - e) ){
                // drop this letter
                splittedWord.splice(e, 1, '_');
                dropped++;
            }
        }
        
        //console.log(`Original word: ${selectedWord}`);
        console.log(`Guess the word: ${splittedWord}`);
        
        let removedChars = charMap.filter( (char, index) => {
            if( splittedWord[index] !== char ){
                return char;
            }
        });

        console.log(removedChars);

        let charIndex = -1;
        rl.prompt();
        rl.on('line', (input) => {
            //console.log(input);
            if( removedChars.includes(input) && charMap.includes(input) ){
                charIndex = charMap.indexOf(input, charIndex + 1);
                //console.log(charIndex);
                splittedWord.splice(charIndex, 1, input);
                // splittedWord = splittedWord.map( (char, i) => {
                //     charMap[i] === input ? input : char
                // });
                console.log(`Well done!Gues the next char: ${splittedWord}`);
                rl.prompt();
            } else if( splittedWord.join() === selectedWord ){ 
                console.log('Congratulation, you have found word!');
                rl.close();
                process.exit();
            } else {
                console.log(`Oh noo, wrong letter! Try with a different one!`);
                rl.prompt();
            }
        });

    });
```

I've noticed that if in the searched array there are two identical elements at a different index, only one will be found and the second will be ignored. Is there a solution for this?

Consider this concole output, I have the word `grifferesti`, since the letter `i` is present two times, `indexOf` will only give me the first element found that match the searching criteria. This become a problem because a word can contain duplied charatchers and I need to check for them if they are removed from the word that the user will display and try to guess

```js
[
  'g', 'r', 'i', 'f',
  'f', 'e', 'r', 'e',
  's', 't', 'i'
]
Selected word length is 11
Removed letters: 5
Original word: grifferesti
Guess the word: g,r,_,_,f,e,r,e,_,_,_
[ 'i', 'f', 's', 't', 'i' ]
Please insert a letter: i
i
2
Well done!Gues the next char: g,r,i,_,f,e,r,e,_,_,_
Please insert a letter: f
f
3
Well done!Gues the next char: g,r,i,f,f,e,r,e,_,_,_
Please insert a letter: t
t
9
Well done!Gues the next char: g,r,i,f,f,e,r,e,_,t,_
Please insert a letter: i
i
2
Well done!Gues the next char: g,r,i,f,f,e,r,e,_,t,_
Please insert a letter: s
s
8
Well done!Gues the next char: g,r,i,f,f,e,r,e,s,t,_
```

**UPDATE**

I'm testing the solution provided from the user Hacktish but this is what happen in console when I test the code

```js
Selected word length is 9
Your score: 0
Guess the word: _,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_
Please insert a letter: a
You found the a letter!
Score: 50
,,,,,,,,
Please insert a letter: c
Oh noo!Wrong letter, please retry!
Please insert a letter: b
Oh noo!Wrong letter, please retry!
Please insert a letter: n
You found the n letter!
Score: 0
,,,,,,,,
```

As you can see, the `_` char will be not displayed and the found letter will be not added. I don't know if this can be an implementation issue

```js
splittedWord = charMap.map( () => '_' );

        rl.prompt();
        rl.on('line', (input) => {
            if( charMap.includes(input) ){
                splittedWord = splittedWord.map( (char,i) => {
                    charMap[i] === input ? input : char;
                });
                console.log(`You found the ${input} letter!`);
                score += 50;
                console.log(`Score: ${score}`);
                console.log(`${splittedWord}`);
                rl.prompt();
            } else if( splittedWord.join('') === selectedWord ){
                console.log('Yeah! You found the word!');
                
                rl.close();
            } else {
                console.log('Oh noo!Wrong letter, please retry!');
                score -= 50;
                rl.prompt();
            }
        });
```

Comment: That is the intended behaviour of indexOf - “ The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array” (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: if you want to remove them all, use `filter` instead of `indexOf` + `splice`

Comment: @AnsonMiu - I thought about posting the comment like you did (at the same time), but then again, simple question = simple answer:)

Comment: You can pass in the second parameter to tell the function to start looking after the first 
 found element. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: I don't need to remove the element but get the index and add it to the `splittedWord` array using splice

Comment: newbiedev, with brackets around the arrow function you should add a return: "return charMap[i] === input ? input : char"

Comment: readability, I don't like much to use inline arrow function, solved with the add of `return` before `charMap[i]`

Comment: @Hacktisch do you have a tip to increment score, I'm using `score += 50;` after a char is found but for the first char found not works

Comment: I'm guessing you did not instantiate the score variable at the start of your code: var score=0; or let score=0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers explain you about the behavior of `indexOf`. But this may not be the right function for you to use. You would need a lot of additional functionality to make this work with `indexOf`.

You can solve your problem with less code if you use another function:

```
splittedWords = splittedWords.map((_,i)=>charMap[i]===input?input:_);
```

The above code walks throuw the splitterWords array (`map` function), the `_` is the element in the array, the `i` is the index.
It replaces the element in the array by the result of the ternary operation: If it's original character matches the input, it is replaced by the input. Otherwise it is left the same.

---

**EDIT:**
example code to paste in your JS console

```
const charMap=[
  'k','i','w','i'
]
let splittedWords=charMap.map(()=>'_');
const input='i';
splittedWords=splittedWords.map((_,i)=>charMap[i]===input?input:_);
console.log(splittedWords);
// THIS PRINTS: ["_", "i", "_", "i"]
```

Comment: This would also cause the `input` to be replaced with all the occurrences of that character for the same input. E.g. The first `i` given as input will be substituted to both the places even though the user has only given a single `i` as input.

Comment: `splittedWord.splice(charIndex, 1, input);` at the moment I'm replacing the underscore cha using `splice()`. The `charMap` array hold all the letters of the word before the letters are removed and the `splittedWord` contains the word after the letters are removed. I think that is better to map the `charMap` array and then replace the found letters inside the `splittedWord` array?

Comment: I'm testing with map but it will return only commas after the input `Original word: agguatiate
Guess the word: _,g,_,u,_,_,i,a,t,_
[ 'a', 'g', 'a', 't', 'e' ]
Please insert a letter: g
Well done!Gues the next char: ,,,,,,,,,` As you can see all the letters will be lost

Comment: I edited my answer to include example code you can try.
@MD.TabishMahfuz That's the intended behior because that's how it works with word guessing games. And otherwise, newbiedev didn't have to ask this question because his intial code already worked if the goal was to make the user enter the same character multiple times.

Comment: @Hacktish Yup I can confirm this behaviour had tested it myself. If this is the behaviour newbiedev wants then this is the best way to get it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I've edited the question to include all the code that I have at the moment. @Hacktisch I don't want to imput many times the same char but I was looking for a way that will work when a word have some letters repeated like in your example where `kiwi` have two i. Since the letters are removed randomly, can happen that the user will see `k_w_` and need to input the `i` letter to complete the word. Iìm not sure if I'm explaining myself.

Comment: newbiedev, you added brackets around the arrow function I provided. This means that it doesn't return anything. This may be a bit complicated to understand, you may want to read about arrow function syntax. To fix your current code, add "return": "return charMap[i] === input ? input : char"

Answer (score 1):

No, that's an intended behavior:

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: As I've writed in a comment, I need to find the element index and then add it to the `splittedWord` array. I'm doing an exercise to improve my JS/nodejs skills and I'm making a guess the word game. :)

Comment: In such case, you can do a simple loop - (while indexOf > -1) and keep updating the string and array as you keep on iterating.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in a second parameter the the `indexOf` function to find elements after that specific index.

Shared from the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

```
const beasts = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'bison'];

console.log(beasts.indexOf('bison'));
// expected output: 1

// start from index 2
console.log(beasts.indexOf('bison', 2));
// expected output: 4

console.log(beasts.indexOf('giraffe'));
// expected output: -1
```

A simple function to get all the indexes of an element in the array:

```
function indexesOf(arr, el) {
    let i = -1, indexes = [];
    while ( (i = arr.indexOf(el, i+1)) != -1 )
        indexes.push(i);
    return indexes;
}
```

So what you can do is simply keep an index of the last added item in the `splittedWord`. and then pass in `that index + 1` to the `charMap.indexOf` to get the correct position.

```
// Outside of your loop
let charIndex = -1;

// Inside the loop
....
....
if ( removedChars.includes(input) && charMap.includes(input) ) {
    charIndex = charMap.indexOf(input, charIndex + 1);
    ....
    ....
```

Something like this. Please test and correct this if necessary. I have NOT tested this.

Alternatively, try this:

```
if( removedChars.includes(input) && charMap.includes(input) ){
    let charIndex;
    do {
        charIndex = charMap.indexOf(input, charIndex + 1);
    } while( splittedWord[charIndex] != '_' || charIndex != -1 )
    console.log(charIndex);

    if ( charIndex == -1 ) {
        // Not sure if this can happen in your code
        // Shouldn't happen if you are removing 
        // the characters from removedChars array properly
    } else {
        splittedWord.splice(charIndex, 1, input);
        // splittedWord[charIndex] = input; Should also work I think.
    }
    console.log(`Well done! Guess the next char: ${splittedWord}`);
    rl.prompt();
} else {
    console.log(`Oh noo, wrong letter! Try with a different one!`);
    rl.prompt();
}
```

Comment: Would this custom function I have added in the edit work for you?

Comment: I don't have a loop, I'm simpy thesting the array after the `readline` return an input :). Anyway I will test and let you know, thank you.

Comment: Your `if` is running multiple iterations right? Just put the declaration one level above that scope so that the `charIndex` value persists through multiple calls to this line of code.

Comment: the `if` statement is inside the `readline.on('line')` callback and it's called only after user input

Comment: So just declare `charIndex = -1` outside that callback function to make sure that it's value is persisted from the last call.

Comment: Seems working in this way but sometimes the missing letter, if correct, will be added in the wrong position. Also I need a way to compare the final word with the original one to stop the `readline.prompt()` and restart it with another word

Comment: Can the characters be inserted randomly? i.e. not necessarily in correct order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231116/discussion-between-md-tabish-mahfuz-and-newbiedev).

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own function for that behavior.
`indexOf` returns first matching result, but as MD. Tabish Mahfuz explained already you can continue search by providing 2nd parameter (starting point) to find next matching element.

Basically something like this should work:

```
Array.prototype.indexesOf = function(element) {
  let allIndexes = []
  let index = -1
  //search for all matching elements in array until end of array is reached
  while ((index = this.indexOf(element, index + 1)) >= 0)
    allIndexes.push(index)
  return allIndexes
}
```

Then you can call it like this `[1,2,1,1,3,4,5,2,3,1,1].indexesOf(1)` which should return  `[0, 2, 3, 9, 10]`.

Note: Adding function to `Array` like that is called monkey patching, and in production you might not want to do that as code can get really messy. Instead you can create either wrapper class or function.

Comment: will this work with splice? or I need to call splice more than once to replace the underscore with the found char?

Comment: If  you want to remove elements at all given indexes (returned from `indexesOf()`) with `splice()`, then you need to iterate array in reverse order, otherwise you indexes will mismatch after first removal. I am not sure if this is what you are asking, but something like this should work: `let arr = [1,2,1,1,3,4,5,2,3,1,1]; arr.indexesOf(1).reverse().forEach(index => arr.splice(index, 1))`